# How to declare an array and store records as elements in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Trying to learn pl/sql and wondering if anybody can help declare an array and store records? thanks.

Comment: share you code, what you tried earlier.!!!

Comment: First have a look at this article. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/05_colls.htm

 If you get an error while coding, post it here with the log message.

Comment: Based on the title, what you need is a table, which is basically an array, which contains records ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **[cursor](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/index.php)** to store set of records from a query. But more specifically if you want to add , remove values(like a java array) you can use [**table type**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005)